# jQuery - BW effect using the HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

How can I make a normal image turn to black and white when mouse is over it, and back to normal when mouse is out?

Comment: You want to do it manually or you want a library that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html:

*(Comments my own)*

```
// create canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
// assuming imgObj is a DOM representation of your image, get the width    
var imgW = imgObj.width;
// ... and the height
var imgH = imgObj.height;
// set the canvas to the image dimensions
canvas.width = imgW;
canvas.height = imgH;
// draw the image on the canvas
canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
// get every pixel in the image
var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);
// cycle through the pixels vertically
for(>var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
     // cycle through the pixels horizontally
     for(>var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
          var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
          // create an average grayscale color for the pixel
          var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
          // set the pixel to the newly created average color
          imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
          // do the same for the next two pixels
          imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
          imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
     }
}
// overwrite the canvas image with the newly created array of pixels
canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
// get a data URL which is to be used in the SRC attribute of the image
return canvas.toDataURL();
```

Additionally, if you want a 'plug-and-play' **jQuery plugin** to do this for you, take a look at [this jQuery plugin that desaturates the image for you](https://github.com/josefrichter/jquery-grayscale).

Comment: also the nested fors are a bit ugly, could go with one if you use imgPixels.length

Answer (score 0):

Here would be the function as I see it:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.a").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
            },
            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
            });

     });
```

Here would be the css:

```
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    }

 img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

I got this from here: http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/